# used_in_forms doesn't work properly in magento

Tags: php, magento

I added this code..

```
 Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
        ->getAttribute('customer', 'consumer_id')
        ->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit', 'checkout_register'))
        ->save();
```

I want to hide consumerid from the customer create page and need to display that field on edit page. How to do that?

Comment: Hello, you need to add manually for that page with same name like example your attribute code is test then <input type="text" name="test"/> and magento will save that attribute value automatically

Comment: I added an attribute to my customer entity(via installer script), that field comes automatically on customer creation page as well customer information page from admin panel, but I want to hide that field from creation page and will be displayed on edit page.

Comment: are you using any module? or you have added using script? if you added using script, you must need to add manually so you can add codition

Comment: I am using module which contains the installer script with version numbers. If I remove 'adminhtml_customer' from used_in_forms array, that field is not visible on both the pages. So I think there should be some way to hide those fields on create page rather adding it manuallly.

Comment: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/02/customer-registration-fields-magento1-6/

Comment: I already did that, but this is not.. what I am asking for.
Thanks